# How to convert file content to a string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, 2d

I have a constructor looks like this:

```
MyClassName(File f) throws Exception;
```

and a txt file looks like this:

```
. . . . .
. . . . .
. x . . .
. x x . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
```

When open the file, how do I convert it to a String?

Like this:

```
". . . . .\n
. . . . .\n
. x . . .\n
. x x . .\n
. . . . .\n
. . . . .\n"
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean - it sort of sounds like you want to create a string literal, but you can't have multi-line string literals (not without explicitly concatenating the lines, anyway).

Comment: `new String(Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath()))`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch worth mentioning the file encoding here - platform default might not be correct. Although it shouldn't have much of an impact given the content.

Answer (score 0):

this method reads a file:

```
 public String readFile(File file) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    if (file.exists())
        try {
            //read data from file
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            int c;
            while ((c = fileInputStream.read()) != -1){
                stringBuffer.append((char) c);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

and the call from the constructor

```
public MyClassName(File f) throws Exception{
     String text = readFile(f);
}
```

Comment: Stupid question - how is this better than `new String(Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath()))`? It's certainly **much** longer...